# Swinxy Zoom on image with animated objects above

Tags: jquery, plugins

I'm using the Swinxy Zoom plugin to create a magnifier above a container including animated content which combines various objects on top of a background. My problem is that the plugin is fairly limited in scope for anything more than magnifying a single image. After hacking the plugin Js inflate code a little I managed to insert a wrapping element around the magnifier to create a stage area where I could place animated objects:

```
`<div class="viewport-outer">
   <!-- Custom artwork overlay for magnifying glass -->
   <img src="img/magnify.png" alt="magnify glass" class="magnify-glass">
     <div class="sxy-zoom-viewport">
       <!-- Container space for animated objects -->
       <div class="magnified-display"></div>
         <!-- Object for magnified image -->
         <img galleryimg="no" class="not-visible" />`
```

As the plugin is already minified I couldn't work out which part set the left/top positions for the image and magnifying lens. Hence I've used setInterval to copy the left/top css values over to the 'magnified-display' (offset) and 'magnify-glass' respectively.

var interval1 = setInterval(magnifier, 0);

```
    $('a.magnify').swinxyzoom({
        mode:'lens',
        damping: 1,
        steps: '0',
    })

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.magnifiedContent').appendTo('.magnified-display').each(function() {
            // code for animating appended objects here
        });
    },500)

    $('.sxy-zoom-container').mousemove(function(){
      if($('html').hasClass('.lt-ie9')) {
        $('.sxy-zoom-container').mousemove(function(){
            magnifier()
        })
      }
    })

    function magnifier(){
        $('.magnify-glass').animate({left:$('.sxy-zoom-viewport').css('left')},0)
        $('.magnify-glass').animate({top:$('.sxy-zoom-viewport').css('top')},0)
        $('.magnified-display').animate({left:$('.sxy-zoom-viewport').find('.not-visible').css('left')},0)
        $('.magnified-display').animate({top:$('.sxy-zoom-viewport').find('.not-visible').css('top')},0)
    }
```

This kind of works but creates a lot of lag after a short while due, I think, to using setInterval.